# Restore initial textarea value with jquery if value length < n

Tags: jquery, focus, textarea, blur

I'm new in jquery and javascript coding and I tried to write a function that restores an initial value on a textarea if the length of its value is less than "n" characters. It doesn't work. Can you explain me how to do that?

Here's the code:

```
$("textarea").focus(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val('');
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if($(this).val().lenght<20)
        {
            $(this).val(text);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though not very efficient, this would do the work:

```
var text='';

$("textarea").focus(function() {
    text = $(this).val();
});

$("textarea").blur(function() {
    if($(this).val().length<20)
    {
        $(this).val(text);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is wired that if I don't define the `text` valuable at first then it will cause undefined error. I my option, the blur MUST happens after we leave the focus, and then the `text` is defined there.

Answer (score 2):

`lenght` should be `length`.

Once you fix that, you'll find that you're re-attaching the `blur` event each time but never removing it, meaning you will have tons of listeners attached.  Try `one` or a more generic `blur` attached only once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a closure with a local scope and pass in your variable so that it's local to that scope:

```
$("textarea").focus(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val('');
    (function(initialText) {
        $(this).blur(function() {
            if($(this).val().length < 20)
            {
                $(this).val(initialText);
            }
        });
    })(text);
});
```

If you don't create such a local scope with a closure, then event handler which you pass to `.blur()` won't know what `text` is, since it's not in the scope of this function.

Read more about js closures, e.g. here: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Comment: This doesn't actually change anything.  The `text` variable doesn't change within the function.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I am not really sure what you mean. Have you tested it?

Comment: The blur code already has access to the `text` variable.  If you fix the typo in `length` the original code roughly "works".

Comment: I see. But why roughly, then?

Comment: It re-binds the `blur` every time, meaning there will be n listeners attached after n calls to the code.  It works, but it's bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `.data` function for such cases. See below,

```
$("textarea").one('focus', function() {      //will be executed once
    $(this).data('init_val', $(this).val()); //set data with initial value
    $(this).val('');                         //clear the textarea
}).blur(function() {
    if($(this).val().length<20) {            //Check if entered text val is < 20
       $(this).val($(this).data('init_val'));//If yes, update with initial val
    }
});
```

Comment: I agree, but you still have to fix the `length` typo.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Noted and fixed.. Thanks